# Advanced Segmentaiton: Difference in results between "Include session with page does not match X" and "Exclude session with page matches X"

Tags: google-analytics

To me, these two segments should provide the same results or at least quite close

1 **excludes** only sessions who **DID** see a page
The other **includes** only sessions **who DIDNT** see something

But when I apply these segments, the first segment captures like 80% of sessions and the second one captures 2%

Am I misunderstanding how the condition "Page does not include" actually works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the condition "does not contain" doesn't do exactly what it says. If you apply this filter and go to your Pages report, you'll see the excluded page there.

If you create 2 filters - one to include a page and one to exclude the same page you'll get the total sessions for the selected time range. I always use exclude filters. Cheers!